# ember, nginx, reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ember.js, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have my app deployed to a file server here at:
http://example.com/my-team/my-app

We want our app to be facing at:
http://amazingapp.com

So far this is what I have on nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name http://amazingapp.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://example.com/my-team/my-app/;
  }
}
```

This works for initial `http://amazingapp.com` but any subsequent requests `http://amazingapp.com/post/1/comment/2` result in 404

Most of the ember deploy examples have the file being served from the same location as the web server, using `try_files $uri $uri/ index.html` So i don't believe i'm able to go down that path?

I've tried using regex on the location but that requires the proxy_pass to have parameters.

If you could point me in the right direction would be so grateful. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider your config below

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name http://amazingapp.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://example.com/my-team/my-app;
  }
}
```

When you access `http://amazingapp.com/abc` your location `/` will cut `abc` out of it and append to `proxy_pass`. Making your url as `http://example.com/my-team/my-appabc. Fix is quite simple, just add a trailing`/` to your proxy_pass

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name http://amazingapp.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://example.com/my-team/my-app/;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry i did have the '/' on the proxy_pass. 
w/out the '/' the resource didnt even load. Will update my example.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a 404 on anything besides the initial request.

Comment: Also I hope you don't have `server_name` as `amazingapp.com` and not `http://amazingapp.com`. Just saw that mistake now? Also can you do a `curl -v http://amazingapp.com/post/1/comment/2` and see if that gives something interesting? Another thing please post your nginx access+error logs which show details on the error

Comment: I need the proxy_pass to stay at /example.com/my-team/my-app/
and have the web app handle the routing of /abc/

Comment: @imahungry, i understand that. But I need to know what is going wrong currently. And curl -v and nginx logs would help

Comment: when i curl -v I get a 404
access log:
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2017:12:10:30 -0700] "GET /post/6673?sort=name HTTP/1.1" 404 345 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"

Comment: I am looking for your logs on the example.com server and not here? Do you have access to that or not?

Comment: no i don't have logs to example.com where files are uploaded to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152286/discussion-between-imahungry-and-tarun-lalwani).